# Update Extjs autoEl :'button' text and css dynamically

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, extjs4.1

I am new to ExtJS, want to change the text of a button dynamically:
My requirement is to give preview of button. To provide a preview I have created a component as follows:

```
{
  xtype: 'container',
  width: '100%',
  padding: '20 0 20 0',
  itemId: 'preview-container',
  items: [
       {
          xtype: 'component',
          itemId: 'preview',
          autoEl    :'button'
       }
  ]
}
```

And my update preview method is as follows, I want update the text of the button from this function:
    I have tried like as follows, but not working..

```
updatePreview: function () {
    var previewEl = this.down('#preview').getEl(),
        formValues = this.getForm().getValues(),
        newStyles = {};
    if (previewEl) {
        previewEl.text = formValues.name;
        previewEl.applyStyles(newStyles);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE: Included all my code sample**

```
    Ext.widget({
        xtype   : 'mz-form-widget',
        itemId: 'specialButtonRuleForm',
        defaults: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            editable: false,
            listeners: {
                change: function (cmp) {
                    // alert(1);
                   cmp.up('#specialButtonRuleForm').updatePreview();
                }
            }
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'name',
                fieldLabel: 'Button label',
                allowBlank: false
            },
            {
                xtype: 'container',
                width: '100%',
                padding: '20 0 20 0',
                itemId: 'preview-container',
                    items: [
                        {
                            xtype: 'component',
                            itemId: 'preview',
                            autoEl    :'button'
                        }
                    ]
            }
        ],

        listeners: {
            afterrender: function (cmp) {
                // alert(2);
                cmp.updatePreview();
            }
        },

        updatePreview: function () {
            // alert(3);
            var previewEl = this.down('[itemId=preview]'),
                formValues = this.getForm().getValues(),
                newStyles = {};

            if (previewEl) {
                previewEl.setText(formValues.name);
                previewEl.applyStyles(newStyles);
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're using a component, you don't have the usual button methods.

You would need to do `previewEl.getEl().dom.value = 'New Text';`

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, your selector for the button is wrong as is your method of setting the text.

You need to fetch your button by the itemId

```
var previewEl = this.down('[itemId=preview]');
```

and set the text correctly

```
previewEl.setText(formValues.name);
```

There may be other errors in your code but these are the ones I can spot just by looking. You should spend more time in the documentation too. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext.button.Button

Comment: It doesn't seems to be working for me, I think there might be some issue in my complete code. Please give a look at the update section in the question.

Comment: Component doesn't have a `setText` method.

Comment: Oops, assumed your component was in fact a button.